# Not work update query

Tags: php

Not work login user update query. solve my problem

```
    session_start();
    include_once '../includes/dbcon.php';

    if(isset($_POST['update'])) 
    {
        $firstName = $_POST['firstName'];
        $lastName = $_POST['lastName'];     

        $MySQLiconn->query("Update user Set firstName = '$firstName' LastName = '$lastName' Where user_id=".$_SESSION['login'] ) ;
    }
```

Comment: Your question is about as clear as mud in a black glass. Update your question or check for errors. You're not doing that and clearly contains syntax errors. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Answer (score 2):

Your query should work better like this :

You had forgotten the commas between your fields:

```
 $MySQLiconn->query("UPDATE user SET firstName = '".$firstName."', LastName = '".$lastName."' WHERE user_id=".$_SESSION['login'] ) ;
```

Also we are not an army of coder begging to help you so a little bit of politness could be needed....

Comment: why should it work any better than what they're presently using? Other than the fact that you only put "Update", "Set" and "Where" in uppercase, which has no effect. Those can be in any case.

Comment: I also add commas between each fields that were missing

Comment: Ah for Pete's sake. Yeah sorry about that. You should have made a note about it in your question and for future readers.

Comment: Yup my bad, I edited it ;)